# Building a heap principles- implementing in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, binary-heap

I am having some trouble with my homework.  I was asked to implement a priority queue, using a heap in C++.

While searching for code examples for creating a heap, I encountered many times in this definition:

> An array **A** that represents a heap is an array with two attributes:
>
> – **length**, the number of elements in the array
>
> – **heap-size**, the number of heap elements stored in the array

So my question is this: what is **A**? do I need to implement it by myself (let's say make a class heap which holds 3 fields- array of elements, length, and heap_size)?

I just don't know how to start.

Comment: **A** would be defined by the two words prior to its first usage in the description: *"An array**

Comment: yes, but an array doesn't have the 2 methods length and heap_size... just really dont understand, no need for sarcasm...

Comment: Wasn't being sarcastic (though now that I read it I can see it that way). Truly thought you missed the fundamental data structure they're saying to use; an array construct. templatetypedef's answer is pretty strong, btw, and a good read. with it I would *strongly* suggest you run your homework problem against both the priority queue *you* are implementing *and* try it using a `std::priority_queue<>` as well. The side-by-side validation that you're doing it right will probably be very handy to have.

Comment: Thanks for the re-comment :)... I'll take your advice about the priority queue! anyway, maybe it's a language difficulty (Hebrew), but when I think of array I think of something like this- **int arr[]**... so what I understand is that I need to make an array class?

Comment: You shouldn't need a separate class for your array-backing of your priority queue. They probably want you to use a traditional array (and their use of the word "length" really isn't appropriate; they should have called it *"capacity"*). Do they want you to do this as a `template<>` for arbitrary types, or does the assignment specifically call out something like `int` for this assignment? just curious.

Comment: actually I need to do it both with an array and both with binary tree... but Im trying to understand the basics first, so I'll focus on int... THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binary heap data structure is usually drawn as a binary tree with certain properties, but is typically implemented using a plain array.  The reason for this is that the array version uses less memory than the explicit binary tree and is a lot easier to manipulate.  Consequently, the array **A** that you're seeing described is the array that holds all the values in the heap.

The two fields you are seeing represent the raw total size of that array (**length**), which tracks how much storage space is available, and the number of elements within that array that you are actually using (**heap-size**).  When you insert an element into the heap, you will need to make sure that space exists for it, possibly reallocating the array to be larger and copying over the existing elements, then will need to run a bubble-up operation to insert the new element into the heap.

Typically, though, you would sidestep the logic for maintaining the array and these two fields by layering the heap on top of a dynamic array, like the C++ `std::vector` or Java `ArrayList`.  That way, the logic to track storage space and grow the array is handled for you automatically.

Depending on the assignment parameters, since this is being done in C++, you might want to look into the `std::make_heap`, `std::push_heap`, and `std::pop_heap` algorithms from the `<algorithm>` header.  They make it very easy to implement a heap on top of an existing container like `std::vector`.  In fact, this is how the `std::priority_queue` class is typically implemented.

If you need to implement the heap operations yourself, you might want to check out **[the description of a binary heap given in this assignment handout](http://www.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs106b/cs106b.1126/handouts/190%20Assignment%205.pdf#page=5)**, which seems to closely match the assignment you've been given.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank! didnt think about looking for <algorithm> library... so I was right about needing to implement this class by myself? (in case i dont want to use the STD)

Comment: @omi- If you aren't using the standard libraries or third-party libraries, you pretty much have to implement it yourself.  Depending on the assignment, though, you might be able to use some of the existing libraries.  Check with your instructor to see what's allowed.

Comment: @omi I really wish each assignment given like this would have a detailed list of allowable standard library classes you can use, provided by the instructor. For this problem, things like `std::vector<>` would really come in handy, though they would probably frown on using `std::make_heap` (maybe not though. definitely ask for some clarity).

Comment: I guess I can use any library I want... 'std::vector<>' is allowed for sure!

Comment: @omi I'm going to *guess* that your instructor would frown on using `std::priority_queue<int>` for this assignment =P.., but if `std::vector<>` and `std::make_heap<>` are available to you that would terrific.